# Adding a background image in sass

Tags: vue.js, sass

Having a trouble placing a background image in one of simple Vue.js project that I'm currently doing!

I've tried all the possible solutions that I could come up with. But no luck. That's why I'm here to have experts' help like you!

Having created the hero section, I tried to add a background image to that. Yes, the background image is imported to the right folder and the location of the folder is correctly written as well. However, once the compiler compiled the program, I get crickets! Nothing!

Here's the Sass code

```
.hero
    background: url ('..../assets/clouds.jpg')
    background-size: cover
    background-color:#ffffff
```

[image: Sass code]

And here's the HTML code for your reference

```html
 <div class = "home">
    <section class="hero">
      <div class="hero-body">
        <div class=" container">
          <h1 class="title"> {{heading}} </h1>
          <div class="is-two-thids column is-paddingless"> 
            <h2 class="subtitile is-4"> {{subheading}} </h2>
          </div>

          <a class="button is-large is-primary" id ="learn"> Learn More</a> 
        </div>  
      </div>   
    </section>  
  </div>
```

[image: HTML code]

The funny thing is there's no error message shown. That's right, zero error messages.

This is the final product I received

[image: Output]

For most of you out there, this should be a pretty simple fix. So, can you help this beginner out from this agony!

Thank you!

Edit: Got the following error message after adapting the change

background: url ('@/assets/clouds.jpg')

[image]

Edit 2: Sass file and its location.

It's location is src/router/mq.saas

[image]

Edit 3: Got the required one

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you expect `....` to refer to?

Comment: To the "src" folder in which you have the "asset" folder. In asset folder, you have the image  "clouds.jpg"

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `../..`? Only `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory) are valid path traversal symbols. There is no `....`

Comment: Then that might be the error. So, the correct way is . . / ? Let me try it and see what happen

Comment: You mean the image file or..?

Comment: Looks like you're using Vue CLI v2. This is deprecated and no longer supported. If you're following a tutorial, it is out of date. See https://cli.vuejs.org/ for a modern equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `..../` is not a valid relative-path traversal symbol. Only `./` (current directory) or `../` (parent directory) are valid.

Assuming you've built the app with Vue CLI (**v3**), you should be able to use

```css
background: url ('@/assets/clouds.jpg')
```

where `@` is configured as an alias for `<projectRoot>/src`.

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules

---

Alternately, construct a valid relative path from your Sass file / Vue component.

For example, say you're in `src/mq.sass` and want to reference `src/assets/clouds.jpg`, the relative path would be

```css
background: url('./assets/clouds.jpg')
```

Comment: Yes, I did use the CLI. Let me add this change and see what happens. Thanks Phil!

Comment: Hey Phil, let me be honest. I am an absolute beginner, so I know nothing about this. I am trying to learn this. So, bare with me! What's the difference between v2 and v3

Comment: Anyway, I adapt your change, and this time it gives me an error message. Would you like to see through it Phil?

Comment: Compiler say that some relative module isn't found! What could be the error here. I could send you a screen shot of it. But in comment sections, it's not possible to do

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the `@` alias is only valid if using Vue CLI v3. Since you are using v2, try the second part of my answer using a valid relative path

Comment: Hey Phil, I added the screen shot of the sass file and its location, so you can see clearly what's going on! Thanks for the help brother

Comment: Phil, I tried your second part and it worked! hooray! Thanks!

Comment: Is that the Sass file with your `.hero` class? Doesn't look like it's in `router`. The screenshot shows it in `src/mq.sass` in which case, the relative path is `./assets/clouds.jpg`

Comment: So, I did change that path to ./assets/clouds.jpg and it worked! What was the error then Phil?

Comment: Oh shoot, it's in the "src" folder. Anyway now everything works fine! What was the error there brother?

Comment: Thanks for the help Phil. Btw, should I have VUE3?

Comment: Vue **CLI** v3 (which is separate to Vue) and yes, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll shift into that soon